# prevent emacs from splitting vertically?

Tags: emacs

My Mac has Emacs v22 and it only splits horizontally when I type ^x-2.

My Linux system has Emacs v24 and it splits vertically when Emacs thinks that's a better choice. The problem is, I don't want it to split that way. How do I prevent emacs from splitting vertically?

Comment: Odd as the manual shows C-x 2 (split-window-below). Look in the .emacs settings file or the customization interface and check if this has been re-assigned to split-window-right.

Comment: Type `C-h k C-x 2`. Is the key properly set to `split-window-below`?

Comment: The problem seems to show up with grep, compile, goto next error, and gdb commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the Emacs manual, node `Window Choice`.  In particular, see user options `split-height-threshold` and `split-width-threshold`.

Specifically, add this to your .emacs file:

```
(setq split-width-threshold nil)
```

Answer (score 4):

For splitting horizontally use `C-x 3`. You can find more options [here.](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_winner_mode.html)